# Undefined reference to tensorflow::function `operator()'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow1.15

I have version TensorFlow_gpu_1_15_0 installed and it works fine. I used the following commands for testing :

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
True
>>> tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None)
True
>>>
```

But when I try to compile a pre-made file with c ++, I get a series of errors, such as:

```
[build] D:/project/.../obj_loader/obj_loader.cpp:22: undefined reference to `tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext::MakeShape(std::initializer_list<tensorflow::shape_inference::DimensionOrConstant>)'
[build] D:/project/.../obj_loader/obj_loader.cpp:122: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN10tensorflow10DEVICE_CPUE'
[build] D:/project/.../obj_loader/obj_loader.cpp:122: undefined reference to `tensorflow::KernelDefBuilder::Device(char const*)'
[build] C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/site-packages/tensorflow_core/include/tensorflow/core/lib/core/refcount.h:90: undefined reference to `tensorflow::internal::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int)'
```

And other errors.
Any help or reference would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I apologize if the question is not clear!
My question is, why can't I use pre-built libraries like shape_inference (which is a Tensorflow library) in my project?

Comment: In fact, I want to use the functions available in the **Tensorflow libraries** in my application, which is written in **C ++**!

Comment: For example, **I connect to the shape_inference library and when I want to use the MakeShape function with an undefined reference to:**

Comment: tensorflow :: shape_inference :: InferenceContext :: MakeShape (std :: initializer_list <tensorflow :: shape_inference :: DimensionOrConstant>)

Comment: 'I encounter.
I want to know where the problem comes from? Is this inconsistency due to my tensor flow version?